# How to create static folder on publish?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to use additional static foldr, so I added app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions{}) in Startup.cs:

```
namespace DailyAnlytics
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
               //...
            });

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Mycustomfolder")),
                RequestPath = "/Mycustomfolder"
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("default", "main{controller}/{action?}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If there no folder Mycustomfolder in publish directory, application just don't starting. How make application create this folder if it's not exist?

Comment: You can always add it to your program.cs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serve static files outside wwwroot, but handle PhysicalFileProvider when directory does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526818/serve-static-files-outside-wwwroot-but-handle-physicalfileprovider-when-directo)